# PHP Count Values json inside Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, count

I just wanna count values data inside foreach. If values same it will count
Like if "Shared Hosting - Starter" has 6 value then count and print "Shared Hosting - Starter (6)"

This is my code

````
$emailtemplates = '{"result":"success","totalresults":13,"startnumber":0,"numreturned":13,"orders":{"order":[{"id":121,"ordernum":1991897965,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-09 09:38:14","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000017,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"ovh test lagi","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":114,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":120,"ordernum":6100408413,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-07 14:48:55","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000016,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test hosting","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":113,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"ewfwfhl.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":119,"ordernum":5975662952,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-06 07:48:48","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000014,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test email not to spam","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":112,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":116,"ordernum":8975405194,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-05 13:46:37","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000010,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test ovh","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":[]},{"id":114,"ordernum":9059646332,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-03 08:08:31","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000008,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":107,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Cancelled"}]}},{"id":113,"ordernum":5332646679,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-02 16:53:17","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000007,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test cpanel","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":106,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby1234.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":112,"ordernum":4793578376,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-02 09:50:31","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":1000000006,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"iPay88 Payment Completed.","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":105,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasurabayanow.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":70,"ordernum":6736003294,"userid":3,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-29 16:26:53","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":0,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"91.192.166.30","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":null,"name":"Modulesgarden Support","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":63,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Value","domain":"mgtest2.com","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":56,"ordernum":1999753213,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-24 11:45:46","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"30200.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":72,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"test","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":49,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"iwansakti.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.20,000 IDR","status":"Active"},{"type":"domain","relid":20,"producttype":"Domain","product":"Register","domain":"iwansakti.xyz","billingcycle":1,"amount":"Rp.10,200 IDR","status":"Active","dnsmanagement":1,"emailforwarding":0,"idprotection":0}]}},{"id":31,"ordernum":3357231065,"userid":3,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-18 13:57:53","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":34,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"91.192.166.30","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Unpaid","name":"Modulesgarden Support","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":31,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"vps-d1dcb601.vps.ovh.ca","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Suspended"}]}},{"id":30,"ordernum":2871924540,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 14:25:54","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":33,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"test ovh 3","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":30,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Terminated"}]}},{"id":29,"ordernum":6918336188,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 04:22:36","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":32,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"Test beli iwan 2","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":29,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Cancelled"}]}},{"id":28,"ordernum":1295130072,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 03:24:46","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":31,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"order pertama","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":28,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}}]}}';

//kita decode dulu
$decodenya = json_decode($emailtemplates, true);

echo "<pre>";
//print_r($decodenya);
echo "</pre><br/>";
$count=1;
foreach ($decodenya["orders"]["order"] as $key=>$oder){
    foreach($oder["lineitems"]["lineitem"] as $key1=>$oder1){
        
        $hitung = $oder1["product"];
        if ($hitung == $hitung){
            
            $count=1;
            $values[] = $oder1;
            $count++;
            echo $count;
            //$count = 0;
            
        } else if ($hitung == $hitung){
            $count = 1;
            $values[] = $oder1;
            $count++;
            echo $count;
            
        } else if ($hitung == $hitung) {
            $count = 1;
            $values[] = $oder1;
            $count++;
            echo $count;
            
        }
        
    }
        
}

?>```

The output is 2222222222222
any help will be greatly appreciated
````

Comment: You are declaring you `$count` 2 times so declare it only outside of the loop and try it.

Comment: I just added `echo $count;` outside the loop and output is `23456789101112131414`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the solution what you looking for. Just run the code.

```
$emailtemplates = '{"result":"success","totalresults":13,"startnumber":0,"numreturned":13,"orders":{"order":[{"id":121,"ordernum":1991897965,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-09 09:38:14","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000017,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"ovh test lagi","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":114,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":120,"ordernum":6100408413,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-07 14:48:55","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000016,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test hosting","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":113,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"ewfwfhl.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":119,"ordernum":5975662952,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-06 07:48:48","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000014,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test email not to spam","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":112,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":116,"ordernum":8975405194,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-05 13:46:37","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000010,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test ovh","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":[]},{"id":114,"ordernum":9059646332,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-03 08:08:31","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000008,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":107,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Cancelled"}]}},{"id":113,"ordernum":5332646679,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-02 16:53:17","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000007,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test cpanel","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":106,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby1234.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":112,"ordernum":4793578376,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-02 09:50:31","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":1000000006,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"iPay88 Payment Completed.","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":105,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasurabayanow.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":70,"ordernum":6736003294,"userid":3,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-29 16:26:53","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":0,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"91.192.166.30","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":null,"name":"Modulesgarden Support","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":63,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Value","domain":"mgtest2.com","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":56,"ordernum":1999753213,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-24 11:45:46","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"30200.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":72,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"test","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":49,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"iwansakti.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.20,000 IDR","status":"Active"},{"type":"domain","relid":20,"producttype":"Domain","product":"Register","domain":"iwansakti.xyz","billingcycle":1,"amount":"Rp.10,200 IDR","status":"Active","dnsmanagement":1,"emailforwarding":0,"idprotection":0}]}},{"id":31,"ordernum":3357231065,"userid":3,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-18 13:57:53","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":34,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"91.192.166.30","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Unpaid","name":"Modulesgarden Support","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":31,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"vps-d1dcb601.vps.ovh.ca","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Suspended"}]}},{"id":30,"ordernum":2871924540,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 14:25:54","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":33,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"test ovh 3","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":30,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Terminated"}]}},{"id":29,"ordernum":6918336188,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 04:22:36","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":32,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"Test beli iwan 2","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":29,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Cancelled"}]}},{"id":28,"ordernum":1295130072,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 03:24:46","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":31,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"order pertama","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":28,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}}]}}';

//kita decode dulu
$decodenya = json_decode($emailtemplates, true);
$arrayAfterCount=array();//It will store product as a key and count as a value
foreach ($decodenya["orders"]["order"] as $key=>$oder){
    if(isset($oder["lineitems"]["lineitem"])){
        foreach($oder["lineitems"]["lineitem"] as $key1=>$oder1){
            if(isset($arrayAfterCount[$oder1['product']])){
                //If the product found again then the value will increase by one
                $arrayAfterCount[$oder1['product']]++;
            }else{
                //The product is found for the first time
                $arrayAfterCount[$oder1['product']]=1;
            }  
        }
    }   
}
//Print the output
foreach ($arrayAfterCount as $key => $value) {
    echo "{$key} ({$value}) <br/>";
}
```

Output:

```
VPS Linux - VPS Starter (5)
Shared Hosting - Starter (6)
VPS Linux - VPS Value (1)
Register (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard functions you can achieve the result easily.

```
$emailtemplates = '{"result":"success","totalresults":13,"startnumber":0,"numreturned":13,"orders":{"order":[{"id":121,"ordernum":1991897965,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-09 09:38:14","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000017,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"ovh test lagi","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":114,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":120,"ordernum":6100408413,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-07 14:48:55","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000016,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test hosting","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":113,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"ewfwfhl.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":119,"ordernum":5975662952,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-06 07:48:48","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000014,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test email not to spam","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":112,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":116,"ordernum":8975405194,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-05 13:46:37","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000010,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test ovh","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":[]},{"id":114,"ordernum":9059646332,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-03 08:08:31","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000008,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":107,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Cancelled"}]}},{"id":113,"ordernum":5332646679,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-02 16:53:17","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"banktransfer","invoiceid":1000000007,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"test cpanel","paymentmethodname":"Bank Transfer","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":106,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasby1234.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":112,"ordernum":4793578376,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-10-02 09:50:31","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"[]","amount":"10000.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":1000000006,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"maxmind","fraudoutput":"{\u0022code\u0022:\u0022ACCOUNT_ID_REQUIRED\u0022,\u0022error\u0022:\u0022An account ID and license key are required to use this service.\u0022,\u0022http_response_code\u0022:401}","notes":"iPay88 Payment Completed.","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":105,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"beritasurabayanow.my.id","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.10,000 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":70,"ordernum":6736003294,"userid":3,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-29 16:26:53","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":0,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"91.192.166.30","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":null,"name":"Modulesgarden Support","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":63,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Value","domain":"mgtest2.com","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}},{"id":56,"ordernum":1999753213,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-24 11:45:46","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"30200.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":72,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"test","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":49,"producttype":"Hosting Account","product":"Shared Hosting - Starter","domain":"iwansakti.xyz","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.20,000 IDR","status":"Active"},{"type":"domain","relid":20,"producttype":"Domain","product":"Register","domain":"iwansakti.xyz","billingcycle":1,"amount":"Rp.10,200 IDR","status":"Active","dnsmanagement":1,"emailforwarding":0,"idprotection":0}]}},{"id":31,"ordernum":3357231065,"userid":3,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-18 13:57:53","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":34,"status":"Active","ipaddress":"91.192.166.30","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Unpaid","name":"Modulesgarden Support","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":31,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"vps-d1dcb601.vps.ovh.ca","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Suspended"}]}},{"id":30,"ordernum":2871924540,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 14:25:54","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":33,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"test ovh 3","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":30,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Terminated"}]}},{"id":29,"ordernum":6918336188,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 04:22:36","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":32,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"Test beli iwan 2","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":29,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Cancelled"}]}},{"id":28,"ordernum":1295130072,"userid":1,"contactid":0,"date":"2020-09-17 03:24:46","nameservers":"","transfersecret":"","renewals":"","promocode":"","promotype":"","promovalue":"","orderdata":"a:0:{}","amount":"52500.00","paymentmethod":"ipay88","invoiceid":31,"status":"Cancelled","ipaddress":"0.0.0.0","fraudmodule":"","fraudoutput":"","notes":"order pertama","paymentmethodname":"Pembayaran Online","paymentstatus":"Paid","name":"iwan nasrulloh","currencyprefix":"Rp.","currencysuffix":" IDR","frauddata":"","lineitems":{"lineitem":[{"type":"product","relid":28,"producttype":"Other Product/Service","product":"VPS Linux - VPS Starter","domain":"","billingcycle":"Monthly","amount":"Rp.52,500 IDR","status":"Active"}]}}]}}';

//kita decode dulu
$decodenya = json_decode($emailtemplates, true);

$orders = array_column( (array_column( $decodenya['orders']['order'], 'lineitems')), 'lineitem' );

$product_counter = [];
foreach ($orders as $order_key => $each_order ) {
    foreach ($each_order as $product) {
        if ( isset ($product_counter[ $product['product'] ] ) ){
          ++$product_counter[ $product['product'] ];
        }else{
          $product_counter[ $product['product'] ] = 1;
        }
    }
}

var_dump( $product_counter );
```